# yeoman react-webpack failed to create a project. phantomjs not compatible

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, phantomjs, yeoman

i recently installed the yeoman webpack to create a react-projekt.

i managed to install the newest version of nodejs ( v6.0.0 ), npm ( v3.8.6 ) and yeoman ( v1.8.1 ).

when i create a new project the bash tells me that fsevents@1.0.12 is no compatible with my OS or architecture. i tried to install phantomjs with NPM but it cannot install it. (see the screenshots below)

has anyone a solution for this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Ccb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using webpack with the right config and dependencies.